# Https Request payload too large. Help me in understanding the concept

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, https

I am trying to send a base64 string of a file in an axios request body. The file size is arond 370KB.

I got request payload too large 413 error. After doing some research in internet learned that server is limiting the request size.

Till now my understanding is clear.

Now I changed it to formData and passing that form data as a request body. And I am not getting any 413 error. Server neatly provessed my request.

So what hapenned between formData and server?

*Server is running on Nginx, Node, Express.*

Answer (score 2):

By default `axios` sends data as JSON and on Node.js side JSON parser has a default limit of 100KB. So you can either continue to use formData or increase a limit in JSON parser options.

```js
    app.use(json({
        limit: '20mb'
    }));
```

But if you intend to send large content often then consider using formData or even send content as binary.

**Upd.** For FormData if you usually will process it by `multer` you will have the following limits by default:

```
Field size: 1048576 bytes
File size: unlimited
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. So Json has a limit and formData does not have a limit. This is what you're saying right?

Comment: See update in my answer